# Commit confusion when using git in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

I just began to use git in Visual Studio 2010, but here comes a question. I followed some tutorials on the Internet. But after commitment, my code files marked by lock marks instead of green check marks. Then, I ignore this problem and continue to push it. But when I push it, a message box show up to remind me that "The branch master does not have tracking reference. Do you want to add a tracking reference to master?". I clicked "Yes" option and continue to push. Naturally, I couldn't push the project to the remote. So, is there anyone who can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which plugin are you using? Also, what does `git status` say?

Comment: I presume you are using "git source control provider". There, the lock mark means that the file is NOT changed. The green checkmark means that the file is changed. I know little bit confusing ... but they follow TFS convention. As of the problem with the push, could you write what exactly happens after push?